# Cordova dosen't install on Node 0.11.14 or nightly builds

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

I need to install cordova. my node version is 0.11.14. i use this version beacause i use `KOA`.but when i run `npm install -g cordova` i get this erorr:

```
 PS F:\try\myApp1> npm install -g cordova
 npm WARN engine cordova-js@3.6.4: wanted: {"node":"~0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"0.11.14-nightly-                                    20140819-pre","npm":"1.4
   .21"})
       npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} (current:                                      {"node":"0.11.14-nightly-20140819-pre","n
 pm":"1.4.21"})
        C:\Users\mohammad\AppData\Roaming\npm\cordova ->                     C:\Users\mohammad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\bin\cordova
        cordova@3.6.3-0.2.13 C:\Users\mohammad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova
    ├── q@0.9.7
    ├── underscore@1.4.4
    ├── nopt@2.2.1 (abbrev@1.0.5)
    └── cordova-lib@0.21.13 (osenv@0.0.3, properties-parser@0.2.3, bplist-parser@0.0.5,             mime@1.2.11, unorm@1.3.3, semver@2.0
   .11, shelljs@0.1.4, npmconf@0.1.16, rc@0.3.0, dep-graph@1.1.0, xcode@0.6.7, glob@3.2.11, elementtree@0.1.5, tar@0.1.20,
   request@2.22.0, npm@1.3.4, plist@1.0.1, cordova-js@3.6.4)
```

so it say cordova need 0.10 but i need 0.11.14 for some works . how to solve this issue.

Comment: You could use something like [n](https://www.npmjs.org/package/n) to manage multiple versions of node.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to solve, its just a Warning not an Error.

Run ***cordova*** on the command line and it should print help text.

You can check the [official doc](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.6.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface) on the project website.

Comment: Although it printed those warnings, it still installed, and you should be able to run the cordova command.